# if conditions in vertex shader causes "no buffer is bound to enabled attribute" error on Android 10 browsers

Tags: shader, webgl

I encountered a weird problem. I use WebGL to render a map in browsers. The map is ok on every platform but Android 10 browsers.

There is a shader for drawing dashed lines in the map. On Android 10 browsers when drawing dashed lines there are "INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements: no buffer is bound to enabled attribute" error displayed in the console.

[image]

I removed two if conditions in the vertex shader and no errors display(as the following shows).

[image]

But other if conditions doesn't cause the error.

There is a webapp online that use this map now(https://yongche.baidu.com). On platform other than Android 10 everything display correctly. But on Android 10 the dashed line or railways on map will not display due to this error.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can only guess but,

if an attribute is not used it will may be optimized out. By removing the conditions you might no longer be using `texcoord_y`. If `texcoord_y` is an attribute and it gets optimized out than that may affect the location of the attributes. Which suggests the way the code is using attribute locations is wrong.

You have to always either look up attribute locations with `gl.getAttribLocation` or you have to assign them before linking with `gl.bindAttribLocation`.

Assume you have a shader that declares

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute float texcoord_y;
...
```

The locations of `position` and `texcoord_y` are undefined. If you guess `position` is location 1 and `texcoord_y` is position 0 things might work by luck (since that could be different on another device/driver/browser) but when `texcoord_y` is optimized out and suddenly `position` is location 0 your code will fail.

locations are both implentation specific **and** per program specific. So, just because shader-pair A has `position` at location 0 and `texcoord_y` at position 1 does not mean they'll be the same on shader-pair B.

You always need to either look them up after linking for each and every program or you need to bind them before linking to ensure the are what you want.

I can't know this is your issue but that error and your editing the shader is what it suggests to me. That somewhere the code is not using attribute locations correctly. With the conditions commented out the bug is hidden. With it commented in the bug shows up. You could be looking up or binding the locations correctly but maybe somewhere you have a typo related to setting up attributes. For example a line like

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

That was copied and pasted somewhere else and `positionLocation` was not changed to the correct variable.